# Cassandra write query timeout out after PT2S

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have cassandra monolithic application where I want to write at high rate reading some payloads from queue. Cassandra cluster has 3 nodes . When i start processing large number of messages in parallel(by spawning threads) I get below exceptions

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
```

I am creating CQLsession as bean

```
return CqlSession.builder().addContactPoints(contactPoints)
            /*.addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9042))*/
            .withConfigLoader(new DefaultDriverConfigLoader()).withLocalDatacenter("datacenter1")
            .addTypeCodecs(new CustomDateCodec())
            .withKeyspace("dev").build();
```

I am injecting this CqlSession into my mapper and other classes to run queries

In my datastax driver i have given ip of 3 nodes as contact points
Is there any tuning I need to do in CQLsession creation/ or my cassandra nodes so that they can take is writes at high concurrency ?
Also How many writes can I do in parallel ?

**All are update statement without any if condition only on primary key**

Comment: can you show how do you write data? do you use batches? What is the source of the data? Kafka or something like?

Comment: Source is payload from kafka , which is processed and writes to multiple tables . Some are batch where i know parition key is same and some are async normal writes

Comment: I am using cassandra 4 beta.. Could that be issue ?

Comment: No... it shouldn't be linked to the Cassandra 4 - it's supported version

Comment: I would recommend to try DataStax's Kafka connector (https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html) instead of the manually written code

Comment: I have custom code which i need to do processing on message before writing to disk. I am using magnetic disk could that be issue ?

Comment: Are you limiting the number of async threads?  If not, there might be too many and they could be getting dropped.

Comment: when you're writing then limit is usually memory/CPU, but could be a disk when doing flushes, etc.

Comment: I haven't done any custom config. CPU memory are well below 50 percent

Answer (score 8):

The timeout you're seeing is a result of your app overloading the cluster, effectively doing a DDoS attack.

`PT2S` is the 2-second write timeout. There will come a point when the commitlog disks can only take so much write IO. If you're seeing dropped mutations in the logs or `nodetool tpstats`, that's confirmation that the commitlog can't keep up with the writes.

If your cluster can sustain 10K writes/sec but your app is doing 20K writes then you need to double the size of your cluster (add more nodes) to support the throughput requirements. Cheers!

Comment: Yes I was using magnetic disk to check if I can save cost. once i moved to SSD issue was solved..

Comment: I'm getting it during read stress test. Write size distribution metric shows 60B (bytes) size. What does Cassandra try to write during READ ONLY stress test?

Comment: @Capacytron as discussed in a different channel, C* stores some metrics even for pure read workloads so there's a tiny amount of writes that takes place. You were getting the `DriverTimeoutException` due to the rate limit on Astra. It is configurable and can be increased on request. Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez what do the initials 'PT' represent?

Comment: @BradSchoening, PT stand for Period and Time—it's part of the ISO 8601 standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations